# how to align axis in R so that two axes intersects

Tags: r

For example, I have the following simple command:

```
x<-rnorm(2000, 0, 30)
hist(x)
```

But the graph shows a gap between the line `y=0` and the x-axis. I want it to be shown in the normal format, where the two axes touch on each other at a particular point `(x0, y0)` which I can specify arbitrarily. What is the option in `R` to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to plot the x-axis separately and use `line` to align it with the 0 coordinate.

```
loc <- hist(x, xaxt="n",bty="l")
axis(1, at=loc$breaks,line=-.75)
```

[image]

Comment: +1, thanks! Looks like what I want. But still the y-axis isn't intersecting with x-axis. Is there any automatic way to `axis(2, at=..., line=-.75)` where ... can be something like `loc$breaks`?

Comment: add `abline(h=0)` and you will get the intersection.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is simply to draw it using `box`, since `plot.histogram` skips much of the plotting setup that would allow you to pass the appropriate `par` settings directly:

```
x<-rnorm(2000, 0, 30)
hist(x)
box(bty = "l")
```

See the section in `par` on `bty` for the possible options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `xlim` and `ylim` in `hist`.

Check

```
?hist
```

AND

```
hist(x, xlim = c(-100, 100), ylim = c(0, 500))
```

Comment: This does not address my question. I want to move the x-axis up a little bit and want the axis label not be separated from the actual axis, i.e. eliminate the gap between the x-axis and the x-axis label.